# Searching friends checked in at a location using graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

When I search this text ***My friends who visited San Diego, California*** in facebook I get 12 friends. The URL is https:// www.facebook.com/search/110714572282163/visitors/me/friends/intersect.

I want to do the same thing using *[search](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search)* Graph API which I did using the below URL:

https:// graph.facebook.com/search?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&place=110714572282163&type=location

But this is returning me only 2 friends. Another option I tried was by specifying a lat,lang and distance in query string.

https:// graph.facebook.com/search?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&place=110714572282163&type=location&**center=32.715%2C-117.1625&distance=15000**

The above URL returned 7 friends.

What would I need to do in order for me to get the proper result?

Thank you

Comment: There is no API for the new Graph Search feature yet. And what result is the “proper” one might be up for discussion … the Graph Search runs on facebook.com itself, where it is normal that you can see more stuff then via Graph API. F.e. some of your friends that you see might have “opted out of the platform”, meaning no data about them whatsoever is ever handed out to any app, they are just invisible to apps.

Comment: Thanks CBroe. I was under the same assumption that the search in Facebook.com might have its own internal capabilities, but I thought to get some pointers from experts here. Any idea why does the result vary after adding center and distance query string parameters?

Comment: Because place=… searches for objects with location information for this _exact_ place, whereas center and distance (place gets ignored in this case) search in the perimeter of a location.